# Which standard errors do I use for the Fama-French three-factor model?

Tags: regression, standard-error, factor-analysis, finance, neweywest

I am doing a linear regression with the Fama-French three-factor model with data from the stock market I built a portfolio out of. (I also use Betting Against Beta, Short Term, Long Term and Momentum Factor.)

Which standard error do I use for this? I often see the Newey West estimator used in scientific papers but I cannot see why.

Comment: Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange might be a better place for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more appropriate kind of standard errors estimator depends on the properties shown by the residuals of your regression. In principle there is not one kind of SE that is optimal for FF3 model, it depend from the data in your hand.

Said that, in financial time series data is usual to face heteroskedasticity *and* autocorrelation in residuals. NW standard error estimator is *robust* for both, in other words it take into account certain form of both. Indeed it represent the most common version of HAC standard errors (heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent). For this reason you easily find this kind of SE in scientific articles in finance. Probably this kind of SE, or some variants implemented in several software, are good for your case.